# CSS Curved Background

Tags: html, css, curve

I've had a look around and cannot find anyone with a solution for this:

The issue: A client of mine is looking to have curved bottom sides to certain divs on their page. Some backgrounds will have a photo, some will have a subtle pattern (making the use of .PNG images difficult like I've done here: www.bootbro.com

So far I have this:

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/dg44thbr/1/

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.alignCenter {
  text-align: center;
}

.padAll {
  padding: 25px;
}

div#banner {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(http://wearepeak.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/testimonial.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 555;
  border-bottom:3px solid red;
}

div#content {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(http://wearepeak.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/ux-787980_1920-1750x750.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -175px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 444;
  border-bottom:3px solid red;
}

div#section {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(http://wearepeak.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/balloons-1750x500.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -175px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 333;
  border-bottom:3px solid red;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.clear::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

.curveContent {
  padding-top: 200px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="banner" class="alignCenter padAll">Content here</div>
<div id="content" class="alignCenter padAll">
  <div class="curveContent">
    <p>Content here</p>
    <p>But on another line! Oh no!</p>
    <p>And another line?! What is this>!</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="section">
  <div class="container clear">
    <div class="curveContent">
      <div class="left col2">

        <p>Content here</p>
        <p>But on another line! Oh no!</p>
        <p>And another line?! What is this>!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="right col2">
        Right text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the radius changes depending on the height of the div - something out of my control as this will be affected by containing content. Also the borders become thinner when they get to the sides.

Does anyone have any potential solutions for this?

Thank you

Comment: What radius should the divs have? Should it be an ellipse or a circle?

Comment: border-adius value can be pixels http://jsfiddle.net/dg44thbr/2/ (or any other units)

Comment: Unsure, ellipse? - if you visit http://www.bootbro.com - see how the curved element works here? (Granted it's by PNG) but this is what we're looking for curve wise. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: @GCyrillus One solution, but the border goes thinner and loses its eclipse curve.

Comment: In order to prevent border going thinner you can change it to box-shadow like so `box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px red;`

Comment: to avoid the portion where the border looses it thickness, you can use neagtive margin also on both sdes http://jsfiddle.net/dg44thbr/7/ or add a shadow http://jsfiddle.net/dg44thbr/8/ (where the value of 15px is the one used to draw the curve)

Comment: @GCyrillus I think you've got it! Not as curved as the client was after, but with all things considered this is the best solution I've seen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Border-radius](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) can take a few static values such as       `border-radius: 0 0 200px 200px  /15px;`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.alignCenter {
  text-align: center;
}

.padAll {
  padding: 25px;
}

div#banner {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(http://wearepeak.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/testimonial.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0 0 200px 200px  /15px;
  z-index: 555;
  border-bottom:3px solid red;
}

div#content {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(http://wearepeak.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/ux-787980_1920-1750x750.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -175px;
  border-radius: 0 0 200px 200px  /15px;
  z-index: 444;
  border-bottom:3px solid red;
  }


div#section {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(http://wearepeak.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/balloons-1750x500.jpg);
  width: 100%;
    margin-top: -175px;
  border-radius: 0 0 200px 200px  /15px;
  z-index: 333;
  border-bottom:3px solid red;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.clear::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

.curveContent {
  padding-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner" class="alignCenter padAll">Content here</div>
<div id="content" class="alignCenter padAll">
  <div class="curveContent">
    <p>Content here</p>
    <p>But on another line! Oh no!</p>
    <p>And another line?! What is this>!</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="section">
  <div class="container clear">
    <div class="curveContent">
      <div class="left col2">

        <p>Content here</p>
        <p>But on another line! Oh no!</p>
        <p>And another line?! What is this>!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="right col2">
        Right text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dg44thbr/3/